# Passing ArrayList to chart variable or I dont know how this is called.. Please take a look

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

```
var categList = [];
var correctRateList = [];
var categAveList = [];
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  var data = {
    labels: [categList[0], categList[1], categList[2], categList[3], categList[4]],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "個人",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            pointBorderColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: [correctRateList[0], correctRateList[1], correctRateList[2], correctRateList[3], correctRateList[4]]
        },
        {
            label: "SCMS",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,153,0,1)",
            pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,1)",
            pointBorderColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,153,0,1)",
            data: [categAveList[0], categAveList[1], categAveList[2], categAveList[3], categAveList[4]]
        }
    ]
  };
```

The number of items on the list is uncertain so the current implementation is not reliable. (it only assumed 5 items) . What I want is to pass the whole list variable on that label and data tag.
when I tried:
    labels: [categList]
it does not show what I want. is there any way to be able to do this?

Comment: This is not about Java.  Please do not tag questions about Javascript with "java" if they have nothing to do with Java.

Comment: What about just `categList`? It’s already an array.

Comment: I tried but its wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm just assign the entire variable like so:

Replace:

```
labels: [categList[0], categList[1], categList[2], categList[3], categList[4]]
```

With

```
labels: categList
```

You can apply the same concept to the `data` property

Comment: damn, it's just like that .. 
What I tried is label : [categList] that's why it didn't work..
thanks anyway..